# Weird west book involving a man (tinker?) traveling in a wagon . Either he or his brother are a werewolf. They're connected by an amulet

Tags: story-identification, novel, western

I have some super-vague memories, but this book keeps popping up in my head. I read it as a paperback book, probably in Ohio, in English, between 2002 and 2006, checked out from the local library. I want to say that the title of the book had "tin" in it. The book had sort of a "weird west" vibe to it, although the action was a bit more settlers in the untrammeled lands recently added to the United States. The protagonist was an adult white male who traveled in a wagon. Either he was a werewolf, or his brother was, and he bore the scars from when his brother first transformed. The two of them are connected by an amulet. For some reason, I want to say that the man worked as a tinker, travelling from town to town, buying broken tools and restoring them for sale. Magic is a common enough aspect of the world that you can hire people to perform hexes or make charms for you and be fairly certain they were on the up-and-up and not just scammers (although those might have existed). I know there was a women involved in the main plotline, but I don't remember exactly what her role was. The overall tone was serious in that there was a risk of people dying, but I don't remember it as being overly dark or pessimistic and there were moments of levity and people bonding.

I remember there being at least one sequel, but I remember even less about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the right set of keywords, `weird west series werewolf protagonist tin`, to elicit the book. It's Devon Monk's *Age of Steam* series, with the first book being *[Dead Iron](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9645260-dead-iron)*.

> In steam age America, men, monsters, machines, and magic battle for the same scrap of earth and sky. In this chaos, bounty hunter Cedar Hunt rides, cursed by lycanthropy and carrying the guilt of his brother's death. Then he's offered hope that his brother may yet survive. All he has to do is find the Holder: a powerful device created by mad devisers-and now in the hands of an ancient Strange who was banished to walk this Earth.
>
> In a land shaped by magic, steam, and iron, where the only things a man can count on are his guns, gears, and grit, Cedar will have to depend on all three if he's going to save his brother and reclaim his soul once and for all...

One of the things that may have been confounding me is that the steampunk technology is more prominent than the magic, although the magic is also present. The second book is *[Tin Swift](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12610321-tin-swift)*, is likely where I got the idea that "tin" was part of the title. The bit about the amulet is a bit more hazy, but I wonder if that's about Rose and her plot trinket.